# Add Polymer gesture listeners depending on variable

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

How can I add the gesture listeners without adding them directly to the template or in the 'listeners' property, so I can add them depending on an option.

e.g.

```
Polymer({
    is: 'my-element',

    properties: {
        enableDrag: Boolean
    },

    listeners: {
        // DO NOT DEFINE HERE
        // 'viewer.track': 'handleTrack'
    },

    ready: function() {
        if(this.enableDrag) {
            // attach listeners to an element here, something like
            // this.$.viewer.addEventListener('track', this.boundHandleTrack);
        }
    }
});
```

I have tried `addEventListener('track', this.boundHandleTrack)` and `setAttribute('on-track', 'handleTrack')` and could not get either to work.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not just have the listener in `listeners` but just ignore the event if `!this.enableDrag`?

Comment: I didn't want the overhead of having all that tracking on the element if not enabled. Your solution below works, and I am not too worried about the performance if it is turned on then off (edge case)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the `listen` method to add gestures imperatively. Fwiw, it's better to observe `enableDrag` rather than relying on the property being configured at `ready` time.

Unfortunately there is no `unlisten` at the moment, because (iirc) the gesture code didn't have support for *removing* listeners at 1.0 (this is Coming Soon[tm]). The shenanigans with `boundHandleTrack` are in there because there is no `unlisten`.

It's easier to just always listen to `on-track` on the target node and no-op the handler (like I had to do below anyway) if it works for your use case.

```
properties: {
  enableDrag: {
    type: Boolean,
    observer: 'enableDragChanged'
  },
  boundHandleTrack: {
    value: function() { return this.handleTrack.bind(this); }
  }
},
enableDragChanged: function(drag) {
  if (drag && this.boundHandleTrack) {
    this.listen(this.$.viewer, 'track', 'boundHandleTrack');
    this.boundHandleTrack = null;
  }
},
handleTrack: function(e) {
  if (!this.enableDrag) return;
  // ... otherwise do stuff
}
```

Comment: Thanks Scott! Completely missed this in the docs, working perfectly (although unlisten would be handy too when that comes, but your solution works)